# Can't Update MySQL Installer

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

Everytime I start MySQL Installer this happens:

[image: first screen]

Then this shows up:

[image: second screen]

I've tried uninstalling everything from MySQL, and trying to update again, but it still shows up. I have no clue as why I can't update it. I don't know if it's relevant, but I have installed Visual Studio 2013 and Bitdefender Total Security 2015 in my PC.

Comment: "Then this shows up" after clicking 'Yes' or 'No' on the previous one?

Comment: The second screen is what you get when you run `msiexec.exe` without any parameters, but I can't tell you why it's appearing! Check your event log (`eventvwr.exe`) for MSIexec errors.

Comment: Maybe you should just click "no" and apply the upgrade later. Something's clearly not right!

Comment: This is what the event log says about it: http://imgur.com/TnYZrN9

Comment: I've never been fond the the MySQL "everything" installer. I find the separate installers cause much less headaches in the long run.